# Conditionally returning objects in Java (without iterators)

Tags: java

Say I have a method `getBook()` within the class Bookshelf. The method should only return a Book object if the Bookshelf isn't empty. However, Java requires the method to return a Book object under all circumstances. I could have a method `isShelfEmpty()` which is called first, but it seems awkward to have to reveal the implementation of the Bookshelf to the caller. What's the cleanest way to do this?

An `Iterator` would make this simpler, but this is for a class project, and we haven't covered iterators in class yet.

**Edit:**

I have thought about returning null, but this seems sort of ugly to me for some reason. Is this the best option, or is there another?

Comment: Well, if you don't return `NULL`, you could return a "dummy" book that represents a lack of books on the bookshelf, and maybe contains an indicator called `isDummyBookBecauseShelfIsEmptyAndIDontWantToReturnNull` so you know that the book you got really isn't a book... but you *have* to return *something*... I think you're betting off checking that the shelf is not empty before trying to take a book from it, but that's just me.

Comment: Returning null seems ugly when you are not used to using null.  Null effectively means "nothing", so after you get comfortable with returning null, you will realize that an empty bookshelf should return nothing when `getBook(...)` is called.

Comment: If this were Scala or Haskell, you could return `Option<Book>` or `Maybe Book` respectively to indicate that no book may be present.

Comment: What is the big deal with checking for null? If Bookshelf has no books, then null is the appropriate response to the request "give me a book". It's effectively saying "there are no books". Returning a dummy "null" book is a bad idea as the caller now needs to check for this special "null" book, which really isn't a book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could return `null` if there is no book available. Then you have to check for `null` every time you ask for a book, of course.

I would implement a method `isBookAvailable()` and throw an exception if the method `getBook()` is called when there is no book available.

Comment: YMMV but I find it a lot easier to handle a null response (when properly documented) than catching exceptions

Comment: I think that returning `null` from `getBook()` would be okay if `isBookAvailable()` exists. The idea is that you can't expect what `getBook()` will return if the get something that you know doesn't exist. Another way to look at it, you could throw `IllegalStateException` which is unchecked, and you don't have to catch anything.

Comment: @matt b: I think the idea is that you don't catch the exception if the book doesn't exist. Clients of the class would be expected to only call `getBook()` if `isBookAvailable()` had returned `true`, so a call to `getBook()` when a book is not available would be an indication of a programming error. By using an exception rather than a possibly silent, ignored `null`, any such error would be caught early.

Answer (score 4):

As tangens said you can return `null` or throw an exception.  Which option you choose depends on whether or not requesting a book from an empty `Bookshelf` is an error or not.

Ideally `Bookshelf` would hold a reference to a collection of `Book` instances which could be empty if need be.  This would be a better abstraction for your model.

Comment: +1: It's nonsense to ask for a book and get one at random. I like the idea to return the collection of available books, which may be empty.

Comment: He said the class hasn't covered iterators, it's possible they haven't done collections either.

Comment: Exactly - I've got more experience with Python than Java, but if Python's anything like Java, that seems like a more sane way to do it. Unfortunately, we haven't touched Collections either. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You have two non-iterator based options.

1. You could return null, which basically would mean that `Book getBook(...)` would return nothing if there are no books on the shelf.

In such a case, the code would look something like:

```
public class BookShelf {

  Book getBook(...) {
    if (empty) {
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

1. You could create a sentinel object, a `Book` that indicates the absence of other books.  If the shelf is empty, you would return the sentinel.

Typically Sentinels are named with a NIL convention, which is similar to `null` but is a full object.  So in your book class you would have something like:

```
public class BookShelf {
  public static final NIL = new Book();

  ...

  public Book getBook(...) {
    if (empty) {
      return NIL;
    }
  }

}
```

This avoids using a null pointer; however, it involves using an extra "NIL" object.  In Java the savings are minimal, but sometimes they are worthwhile.  Basically the code with the first solution looks like

```
if (shelf.getBook(...) == null) {
   System.out.println("We ran out of books!");
}
```

while the code in the second solutions looks like

```
if (shelf.getBook(...) == BookShelf.NIL) {
   System.out.println("We ran out of books!");
}
```

Except since this is Java, the better answer to the second option is

```
if (BookShelf.NIL.equals(shelf.getBook(...))) {
   System.out.println("We ran out of books!");
}
```

So you see, there are a number of ways to solve the problem, but each has different strengths and weaknesses.  The key is that either you return nothing (and write your code to handle nothing being returned), or you return something that means "no books are on the shelf".

Answer (score 1):

You should throw a java.lang.IllegalStateException if there are no Books available.  From the javadocs, an IllegalStateException

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time.  In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

So I would expect the code to look something like:

```
public Book getBook() {
    if(books.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    // return the book, knowing that the books list has at least one item in it.
}
```

Comment: It is a better option than returning null. Because if you won't carry a null around all your code if you forgot to check for emptiness or nullity. It will just fail earlier and with a clean stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to return Null, then you need to return something that is a book or not a book.  To implement this you need a parent class or interface that is something like "BookOrEmptySpace" (Stupid name) that can have children "Book" or "EmptySpace".

The method you are talking about returns a BookOrEmptySpace then you test to see if it's an instanceof Book or an instanceof EmptySpace.

This doesn't add anything unless EmptySpace has some attributes of it's own, so nearly everyone just returns null--in fact, null is exactly what your situation requires and is one of the cases that would be intrinsically intuitive to most programmers.

You might wish to tag it with an annotation--in this case I think it's @Nullable (which would indicate to most programmers that it will return null if there are no books to return)

Answer (score 0):

How would you know there is nothing there if it doesn't return anything if there is nothing?!?!  Eventually you have to test to see if something is there - this can either be done before you try to get something or after you get and then check to see if what you got was a book.

Honestly what do you expect **any** programming language to do in that kind of situation?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways of doing it.

1. Return value based:

   - Return null for no book
   - Check for null values
2. Exception based:

   - Throw exceptions when no books are on shelf
   - Handle exceptions in calling code

Having been programming mostly in C/C++ and Python I can tell you that for a situation where nothing is available and no *concrete* identifier is specified (e.g. `getBookAtIndex(14)`) the convention is to return null, NULL, None, etc. Throwing exceptions is reserved for cases where you expect a book with a rigid identifier to be present and it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, I see a number of viable options, each with their own strengths/weaknesses.

**Return a sentinel object when there's no more books, as described by Edwin Buck:**

```
public Book getBook() {
    public static Book NO_BOOK = new Book();
    if(books.empty()) {
        return NO_BOOK;
    }
    ...
}
book = shelf.getBook();
if(Book.NO_BOOK.equals(book)) {
    // there were no books
}
```

**Return null if there are no more books, as you mentioned you don't want to do**

```
public Book getBook() {
    if(books.empty()) {
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
book = shelf.getBook();
if(book == null) {
    // there were no books
}
```

**Throw an Exception when there are no books left, and implement hasMoreBooks.**

```
public boolean hasMoreBooks() {
    return (! books.empty());
}
public Book getBook() {
    if(books.empty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("no more books");
    }
    ...
}
if(shelf.hasMoreBooks()) {
    book = shelf.getBook();
    // you know it's a valid book here
}
```

**Implement a Maybe type wrapper as per Haskell in other languages.** This type of objects represents something that "may be a Book, or may be Nothing". The caller is then responsible to checking whether it was a valid book or not. For languages that provide good support for this type of operation (pattern matching, etc) and don't support null (null is teh devil ;), this is a good solution. For Java, I tend to think it's overkill.

As for "exposing the implementation", I don't think it's unreasonable for a user to know that a bookshelf can be "out of books", and that it's not possible to get a book from it if that's the case.

**Edit:** I'll add one other note which isn't directly related to this question, but is worth mentioning. One of the benefits of throwing an exception on no book (and implementing hasMoreBooks) is that you don't "always" need to check if there's a book.

For example, if you have a tight loop that iterates through the books and there's a book FAR more often than there isn't one, you can just do something like the following:

```
try {
    while(true) {
        book = shelf.getBook();
        ...
    }
} catch(IllegalStateException ex) {
    // no more books
}
```

To be fair, in most cases that's not all that useful... but if you're worried about the performance cost of having to call hasMoreBooks, and you know you'll very rarely have more books, the above may be handy to consider.